# RecyclerVIew adapter - passing values in adapter - onClickListener

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler View adapter something like this -

```
private FetchDonorListData[] itemsData;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;


    public RecyclerViewAdapter(FetchDonorListData[] itemsData, OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener)
    {
        this.itemsData = itemsData;
        mListener = onItemClickListener;
    }
```

And I am setting this adapter from main activity, Like this -

```
    donorsListView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerDonorsList);
            donorsListView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            LinearLayoutManager dListlayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplication());
            donorsListView.setLayoutManager(dListlayoutManager);
   // dListAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(itemsData, );
            donorsListView.setAdapter(dListAdapter);
            donorsListView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
```

I would really like to know how to make calls to this adapter?

I have read every possible way to make a recycler view but am ending up getting errors and null pointer exceptions.

Null pointer Exception for the method - OnMeasure().

Following is the error -

```
04-19 16:40:12.926    5318-5318/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.nyu.blife_app, PID: 5318
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.onMeasure(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler, android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$State, int, int)' on a null object reference
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:1764)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1260)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:337)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:453)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
    --------- beginning of system
```

I read a no of pages for this error and did what was suggested - setting the layout manager for the recycler view - still getting the error.

I apologize if this question looks silly but I am new to android and stuck at this point. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please double check whether your resource file id's match to the ones in the layout file. It is very common to miss this small thing and thus get a nullpointerexception.

It would be handy if you could post the exact line which gives a nullpointerexception from the logcat.

Comment: I have added the Null Pointer Exception to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the context of the layout manager to

```
    donorListView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager((Activity)this));
```

or

```
     LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
```

Seems like the context of the layout manager is not matching with the context of the recycler view. Make the changes and let me know.